# Delphi TWebBrowser error

Tags: ios, delphi, mobile, delphi-xe5

I am developing an **iOS app** using **Delphi XE5 FireMonkey** (with Update 1).

I download PDFs and store them locally and view them with a TWebBroswer.  This always works the first time I download a document, or when viewing an already downloaded PDF.  However, if I download and view a second PDF, the TWebBrowser does not load the file.

```
if FileExists(filename) then
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('about:blank'); //clear page
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('file://' + filename);
  //filename points to a PDF on the local device and the file 
  //definitly exists

  //first run always works 100%, second run comes into this IF statement
  //but the DidFailLoadWithError is fired
end;
```

I am trying to determine what the error is.  Placing a try...except around the Navigate does not work, and the DidFailLoadWithError does not allow one to find the error. 
See: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=115652 for information on the DidFailLoadWithError 'bug'

```
procedure Tform1.WebBrowser1DidFailLoadWithError(ASender: TObject);
begin
  //ASender is a TWebBrowser
  //No parameter with Error info!
end;
```

Any suggestions as to how I can determine the error that is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make a copy of the FMX source directory, add that directory to your search path and make some tweaks to a couple of files.

When you next build your project it will recompile all those FMX units you copied/tweaked. You may be able to get away with copying just the one(s) you modify, and maybe a couple  more via trial and error, which will make the initial build rather quicker.

In the FMX.WebBrowser.iOS procedure `TiOSWebViewDelegate.webView()` method, take the error parameter and do what is needed to get the error string from it, which basically amounts to calling the `localizedDescription` method, and pass it along to a call to `NSLog`. [Documentation is here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSError/localizedDescription).

Then you can read the error message in the log, either in Console.app on OS X if using the iOS simulator, or in the Console section for your device in the Organizer window of Xcode if using an actual iOS device.

Comment: Thanks, I have managed to find a work-around for my problem but using your suggestion above is most probably what is needed until Embarcadero release a fix for the bug